# Rails can't generate Tempfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chmod, temp, rights

I installed my rails-app via Passenger on my apache but I'm getting a strange error

```
cannot generate tempfile `/var/rails/wo42/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2Fb94bb762c37131f8bb65f843c621876720120401-29970-ha7f1p-9'


Extracted source (around line #24):

21:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
22:     
23:     <!-- Included JS Files  -->
24:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
25:   
26:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
27: </head>
```

It seems to be something with the rights but I set /var/rails/wo42/tmp to chmod 777?

Comment: what account is Apache running as?  Can you log in as that same id? cd to /var/rails,  and see if you can do a 'touch junk'.  If it works, rm the junk file, and cd to the next dir, 'wo42',  and repeat the process.  Eventually you probably get a permission denied, and you'll need to fix it,  you may need to chown or chhgrp on a dir to the userid or group id that apache runs as.

Comment: I changed the group but it doesn't work either! Maybe you can have a look at it: http://alternadev.no-ip.org/wo42/

Comment: That just gives me the error,  so you've verified it's not a permission problem?  chat me if you want some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. Not sure if this will be a permanent fix, but here is what got me past it:

```
rake tmp:clear
```